# Some bluesheets for bike frame size?

Tags: frames

I need some basic bluesheet that illustrates/show the different size/angles of a bike frame, but googling I can't find nothing else than consumer standpoints like for whom an xl bike is aimed for and eccetera, that's not what I do need

different manufactures and models might have different sizes, but most of the models are more or less the same, and can be tracked back to the same oems, by consequence I do think that there is some common ground, or basic rule/formula when making a bike frame of the given sizes like xl or l, someone can tell me what is it, or has any "bluesheets" that can share?

Comment: Try a website like BikeInsights to visually compare 2 bikes. The data is compiled from geometry sheets that most manufacturers make available

Comment: What question are you trying to answer with this data? Are you trying to determine what size bike you need?

Comment: I've closed this question as off topic because it's asking for a learning material recommendation. However, if you focus on the underlying problem that you're trying to solve as @DavidD is suggesting, you're more likely to have an on topic question. If that's significantly different than this question, please ask a new question. If this question can be edited in a way that leaves the existing answers relevant, you can do that and it will be automatically flagged for re-opening.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Are you building your own frame ?

Answer (score 1):

> most of the models are more or less the same, and can be tracked back to the same oems

While it's true that many different brands of bikes are produced under contract by a small number of manufacturers in Taiwan and China, it does not follow that they're "more or less the same" as a result of that. Different labels will spec different materials and dimensions for their bikes when they contract out the manufacturing.

There are some "open mold" carbon frames that are sort of the reverse: a number of different fabricators are using identical molds to produce their bikes (although there may be differences in layups, testing, etc). And these are sometimes sold under the label of a local bike shop.

In any case, all brands have sizing guidance saying "if you're this tall, you should ride this size" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just pick any typical bicycle frame, and look at its geometry specifications. Plenty of manufacturers offer full geometry specifications.

For example, if you're interested in touring bikes, you might want to look at geometry of [Surly Long Haul Trucker](https://surlybikes.com/bikes/long_haul_trucker) (scroll down and click on "GEOMETRY").

It has both versions for 26" wheels (ISO BSD 559mm) and 700C/28" wheels (ISO BSD 622mm), but 700C/28" wheels are available only for large frame sizes. If you're interested in geometry of small sizes of 700C/28" frames, then obviously my example doesn't work, and you need something else such as [Surly Cross Check](https://surlybikes.com/bikes/cross_check).